# constraint the center of mass CoM projection on the ground to stay inside the the pressure cone

Tags: drake

I am trying to constraint the center of mass CoM projection on the ground to stay inside the the pressure cone of a four legged robot.
I wanted to Implement a polyhedral convex set using the half-space representation: {x| A x ≤ b}
I tried to use

```
  V = VPolytope(foot_pose_in_world)
  halfspace_polyhedral = HPolyhedron(V)
```

the `foot_pose_in_world` is a 4-by-2 array. I got this error message
`QH6214 qhull input error: not enough points(2) to construct initial simplex (need 5)`
I tried to add the center

```
  full_hull_verticies = np.concatenate((foot_pose_in_world, center))
  V = VPolytope(full_hull_verticies)
  halfspace_polyhedral = HPolyhedron(V)
```

but I got this error message `QH6214 qhull input error: not enough points(2) to construct initial simplex (need 6)`

What is the correct way to add constraint for CoM to stay inside the pressure cone of the stance legs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll be happy to see that we have [ComInPolyhedronConstraint](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1multibody_1_1_com_in_polyhedron_constraint.html) available for you.

Of course you could make the approach you were trying above work, too.  I believe you need to transpose the input. VPolytope (and all methods in Drake), wants the data to be in column-major format.

```
import numpy as np
from pydrake.geometry.optimization import VPolytope, HPolyhedron

x = np.array([[1,1],[-1,1],[1,-1],[-1,-1]])
V = VPolytope(x.T)
H = HPolyhedron(V) 
print(H.A())
print(H.b())
```